# Get photo from Camera and Save it in SQL Server using Xamarin.Android

Tags: sql-server, image-processing, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Android. I am using Visual Studio 2017 for developing an Android application.

I need to capture an image through camera which I have done the following way:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {

            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");
                Photo.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);
                Photo.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        Snap.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            };
```

Now the problem is I want to save/insert this photo(bitmap) to a Sql Server table in a column type Image so that I may display this photo in a Windows Form Application and further use it in crystal reports.

Comment: and your question is? please read [ask]

Comment: Sorry for putting the question out of the format. I mentioned my question in the last i.e. Now the problem is I want to save/insert this photo(bitmap) to a Sql Server table in a column type Image so that I may display this photo in a Windows Form Application and further use it in crystal reports.

Comment: You don't have to quote your post. I can read the original copy very well. That's not a question, You say what you want but you don't tell us what stops you from doing it.   if you're about to ask how you can solve your problem you should at least present some own efforts. any own ideas? any research done? what's the obstacle you cannot overcome?

Comment: If you want to store an image into SQL Server, you need to read an image file into a byte array, Once you have image data in a byte array, you can easily store this image data in SQL Server using SQL parameters, Here is code https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21208/Store-or-Save-images-in-SQL-Server

Comment: @Piglet Sorry for not being that informative as this is my very first post. Should I edit my post ?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for sharing the article. I have gone through it. Actually I am getting image from Camera Activity and want to store that Image in SQL Server.

Comment: Can you connect the SQL server in your application?

Comment: Yes! Everything done other then the Image :(

Comment: Now you do not know how to convert the bitmap to the byte Array?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Yes I am stuck with this. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to a SQL Server directly from the App is a terrible practice and should be managed by a Web Service instead, because it is very easy to decode the binary of APK or IPA files. Then, a user can just destroy your SQL database. That's why you don't find any tutorials on how to do it.

That being said, when you begin the image capture, your code will look something like this `StartActivityForResult(intent, save_request_code);`

And then you have to override the `OnActivityResult` function that gets called once the picture has been taken (or chosen from the gallery).  If the action was successful, we create a byte array and pass that into SQL

```
private const int save_request_code = 7; // You can use any integer

// "protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)" depending on your Android support library version
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case save_request_code:
            switch ((Result)resultCode) // (Result) conversion not needed if it is already a Result object above 
            {
                case Result.Canceled:
                    break;
                case Result.FirstUser:
                    break;
                case Result.Ok:
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data);
                            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg,100, stream);
                                byte[] array=stream.ToArray();
                                SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(txtConnectionString.Text);
                                string qry = "insert into ImagesStore(OriginalPath,ImageData) values(@OriginalPath, @ImageData)";
                                SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, CN);
                                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)txtImagePath.Text));
                                SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ImageData", (object)imageData));
                                CN.Open();
                                SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                CN.Close();

                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine (ex.Message)
                        }

                    }
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("resultCode");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

It also seems like you did not give you app the permission to read the phone data, so you do that by adding this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Again, please don't put this code into production without using a Web Service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will adhere to your advice for using the web services. I am calling the intent on button click like this:

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
StartActivityForResult(intent, save_request_code);

Camera Opens and when I take the picture, Exception "Java.Lang.NullPointerException: uri " occurs at 
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data);

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to give permissions!